# How to view NSString defined in a given iOS ipa file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, security

I remember I have done this before, but forgot the command.

e.g.

I have a NSString defined in source, e.g.

```
NSString * s = @"secret";
```

I remember I can view the content using the `strings` command, but I forgot the exact command to view it,

e.g.

```
strings my.ipa | grep "secret"
```

does not work. Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible directly with `strings` on an `ipa`, but you can do the following:

1. Rename your `.ipa` file to have the `.zip` extension. `ipa`'s are simply renamed zips.
2. Extract (it should create a directory named `Payload`)
3. `cd` into the `Payload/<app-name>.app`
4. You should have a file named `<app-name>` in the current directory.
5. Call `strings <app-name> | grep secret`.